# how to check if device is moved during last 1 minute using accelerometer xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, accelerometer

am looking for method to detect if device not moved, while last 1 minute using accelerometer xamarin

```
        public double oldx,newx;

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {

            base.OnAppearing();

             if (Accelerometer.IsMonitoring)
                Accelerometer.Stop();
            else
                Accelerometer.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);

            Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometre_ReadingChanged;
            void Accelerometre_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                oldx = e.Reading.Acceleration.X;
            }

            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), () =>
            {
               
                Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometre_ReadingChanged1;
                void Accelerometre_ReadingChanged1(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs ee)
                {
                    newx = ee.Reading.Acceleration.X;
                }

          if(oldx != newx){
         // do somth......
//the problem here always oldx==newx           
}
        });
        }
```

the problem is when i compare oldx and newx always the same value ,
but i want to check if the mobile device cordiante change after 1 minute
any solutions pls , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is to attach an event handler when the view appears. Then you wait a minute and attach another one.

When the accelerometer triggers, *both* event handlers will activate and write `oldx` and `newx` which is why you will see that the both values are the same.

Instead, if I were you, I would simply attach a single event handler and save the value + the time of when the event triggered. Then you can compare that in your timer, when it triggers.

This could look something like:

```cs
private double _lastX;
private double _lastHandledX;

private void Accelerometre_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _lastX = e.Reading.Acceleration.X;
}

private void OnTimerTriggered()
{
    if (_lastX != _lastHandledX)
    {
         // bingo!
    }

    _lastHandledX = _lastX;
}
```

Then start your timer like this instead:

```cs
Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), OnTimerTriggered);
```

So your full listing would look like:

```cs
private double _lastX;
private double _lastHandledX;

private void Accelerometre_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _lastX = e.Reading.Acceleration.X;
}

private void OnTimerTriggered()
{
    if (_lastX != _lastHandledX)
    {
            // bingo!
    }

    _lastHandledX = _lastX;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{

    base.OnAppearing();

    if (Accelerometer.IsMonitoring)
        Accelerometer.Stop();
    else
        Accelerometer.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);

    Accelerometer.ReadingChanged += Accelerometre_ReadingChanged;
    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), OnTimerTriggered);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your quickly answer , but it didnt work , first of all , there is an error, the method OnTimerTriggered must return bool , and the same problem always same value , and it didnt trigger again after 1 min

Comment: maybe i must change return as true and change return type bool ,

Answer (score 0):

You should compare two values the first time and one minute later.

```
private double _firstX;
private double _lastX;
private bool IsFirst;


private void Accelerometre_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerChangedEventArgs e)
{
     _lastX = e.Reading.Acceleration.X;
    if(!IsFirst){
      _firstX = _lastX;
      IsFirst = true;
    }
}

private void OnTimerTriggered()
{        
    //compare _firstX and _lastX
    if(_firstX != _lastX){
       ...
    }
    return true;
}
```